# check if element exists within parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm embedding and appending a youtube video to a div by using the href value and adding it to youtube.com/embed/ +hrefvariable. I just need some guidance in how to check if the youtube video is already in the div, to not run the click function that appends it there. I'm thinking using .length() with the parent div?

Here's the appending function:

```
$(function () {
    $(".youtube").click(function (a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        a = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).attr("href") + '?&iv_load_policy=3&autoplay=1#t=0m12s&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';
        $("#currentvid").html(a);
        $("#currentvid").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1E3);
        return !1
    })
});
```

Comment: @roXon 1E3 === 1000; essentially 1 x 10^3

Answer (score 1):

You could do this `if ($("#currentvid iframe").length) return;` at the top of your click function. I would also recommend storing `$('#currentvid')` in a `var`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the iframe already exists or not use:

```
if ($("iframe").length == 0){
   //iframe doesn't exist yet. Append it.
}
```

If you have multiple iframes, give it an id and check for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe_ele = $("#currentvid").find('iframe');
if (iframe_ele.length > 0) {
    ...
}
```